# How do I load a form inside another form?

Tags: vb.net, forms, treeview

I created a registration form and added a form with features "Update, Delete, Refresh," along with a `DataGridView` to show data from the registration form.

Here's my form:

[image: Featured Form]

Since I inserted a `TreeView`, when I click the Update button as in the picture, I get the error:

> Object Reference Not set to an instance of an object

I think my code in the `TreeView` form is wrong.

This is what I entered:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect

    If e.Node.Text = "Update/Delete Student" Then

        Dim regstu As New Registered_Students

        regstu.MdiParent = Me

        regstu.Show()

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Would help to post the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect

```
If e.Node.Text = "Update/Delete Student" Then

    Dim regstu As New Registered_Students
    Form_father.IsMdiContainer = True
    Form_father.TopLevel = False
    regstu.MdiParent = New Form_father
    Form_father.Panel1_Container.Controls.Add(regstu)
    regstu.Show()

End If
```

End Sub